# jQuery $.position() acting different during the $(document).ready in chrome (webkit?)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, position, document-ready

When I try to get the position of an element in the $(document).ready(function() { }); it gives a different (incorrect) value for position.top in chrome, but correct in firefox. It's off by 15-45px depending on which element it is getting the position for.

I have a list of items within a viewport that has overflow:hidden and I want to get the position of each of these items.

```
<div class='viewport'>
  <div class='item'>Item Info</div>
  <div class='item'>Item Info</div>
  <div class='item'>Item Info</div>
  <div class='item'>Item Info</div>
</div>

.viewport { position:relative; overflow: hidden; }
.item { margin-left: 10px; }
```

When I do `$(".viewport .item").each(function() { var pos = this.position(); });` it will give values, but they're wrong.

Even weirder thing is, if I do this from the console (after the page is done loading) it will return the correct values. It seems like the incorrect values only appear during the $(document).ready.

Is there a way to resolve this so I can still do my positioning during the doc.ready?

Comment: Try `this.offset().top;` instead

Comment: working fine for me in firefox & chrome both except one syntax error of `$(this).position()` instead of `this.position()`

Comment: make sure with zoom of your both browser use `ctrl + 0` for 100% view

Comment: @Trevor: Do you have any parent div outside with a `margin-top`?

Comment: @Trevor: Try with `$(window).load(.....)` instead of `document.ready`

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think I asked this properly. It doesn't have a margin-top. It's in a scrollable viewport and I'm assigning the position values to something else within the viewport, so using offset() won't work, it has to be relative to the viewport.

Comment: @Altair $(window).load(...) worked! Thanks, I'll use this instead of the doc.ready

Answer (score 2):

`position()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/)), like other functions in the `offset` module (and, more in general, in the css modules) depends on the actual position of the elements in the DOM, after they are rendered.

`$(document).ready()`, on the other hand, fires immediately after the DOM is constructed.
On modern browsers, it corresponds to [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading

In `ready`, you can manipulate the DOM safely (attach events, etc.) but you may have problems if you "measure" it. For example, it does not wait for stylesheets to download, or for images to download and be rendered.

You ran into a very annoying problem, as it is extremely platform (browser + jQuery version) dependent: in our case, it was working on two browsers out of three, and even on the third it was working 99% of the time, which indicates it is probably a race condition (JavaScript is single-threaded, but the browser is not).

If you need to measure elements, you are much better off using `$(window).load()`